# WCF service - requests above limit

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

i have a wcf service with this configuration:

```
<serviceThrottling 
  maxConcurrentCalls="10"
  maxConcurrentSessions="10" 
  maxConcurrentInstances="10" />
```

What happens with requests, which are above limit of max concurent connections? Is there any queue, where these requests are waiting for proceed? Is it possible to control number of requests in this queue?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the requests are queued.

> Calls in excess of the limit are queued.

More here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379(v=vs.110).aspx

You can set the length of the queue for your WCF application if it's running in IIS. Set the property **Queue Length** of Application Pool of your WCF application, in **Advanced Settings**.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the queue size if it's a windows hosted service?